# Как правильно (с тире или без тире)?

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, как правильно?

`Кот или кошка – определяется старым, народным способом.`

`Кот или кошка, определяется старым, народным способом.`

Comment: *то есть, другими словами* (из профиля) — то есть = другими словами, то есть два раза написано одно и тоже (эта ошибка называется плеоназм, считается очень серьёзной, хуже, чем пропуск запятой).

Comment: На меня это 100-процентная неошибка. Это очень для меня обычная практика. Не меня учите писать, а, например, иностранцев. Хватит творчество дидяти-то – то есть меня – губить.

Comment: Но для остальных-то ошибка. Это же другие будут читать, а не вы сам. Будут думать что-то типа: "Ха-ха, какую глупую ошибку допустил" (без обид).

Comment: А вы сэр или мэм?

Comment: Сэр............